# What is more efficient in python new array creation or in place array manipulation?

Tags: python, performance

Say I have an array with a couple hundred elements. I need to iterate of the array and replace one or more items in the array with some other item. Which strategy is more efficient in python in terms of speed (I'm not worried about memory)?

For example: I have an array

```
 my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to replace the first 3 elements with one element with the value 123.

Option 1 (inline):

```
my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
my_array.remove(0,3)
my_array.insert(0,123)
```

Option2 (new array creation):

```
my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
my_array = my_array[3:]    
my_array.insert(0,123)
```

Both of the above will options will give a result of:

```
>>> [123,4,5,6]
```

Any comments would be appreciated. Especially if there is options I have missed.

Comment: In Python speak, you have a *list*, not an *array*.

Comment: … and the difference is that arrays generally contain elements of a single type, while you can mix types in lists (see the standard array module, or NumPy arrays).

Comment: I didn't see that in the solutions below but you might need that later: use `del my_array[0:3]` if you want to simply remove items. The advantage, besides clarity, is that it removes the reference to the corresponding items. It has no impact with integers, but could have some for other types. It also works with dictionaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to replace an item or a set of items in a list, you should never use your first option. Removing and adding to a list in the middle is slow ([reference](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-queues)). Your second option is also fairly inefficient, since you're doing two operations for a single replacement.

Instead, just do slice assignment, as eiben's answer instructs. This will be significantly faster and more efficient than either of your methods:

```
>>> my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> my_array[:3] = [123]
>>> my_array
[123, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
arr[0] = x
```

replaces the 0th element with x. You can also replace whole slices.

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> arr[0:3] = [8, 9, 99]
>>> arr
[8, 9, 99, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

And generally it's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Please provide more information or an example.

---

OK, as for your update. The `remove` method doesn't work (remove needs one argument). But the slicing I presented works for your case too:

```
>>> arr
[8, 9, 99, 4, 5, 6]
>>> arr[0:3] = [4]
>>> arr
[4, 4, 5, 6]
```

I would guess it's the fastest method, but do try it with `timeit`. According to my tests it's twice as fast as your "new array" approach.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have updated my question. Hopefully it makes more sense now. I do like your method of replacing. The question is still what is more speed efficient?

Comment: Johan, did you try timing it with the timeit module?

Comment: No I haven't. I don't know about the timeit module. I will go investigate it now :)

Comment: You should because you'll likely find that what intuitively should be faster isn't.  And this is a bit tricky to measure properly.

Comment: And, more importantly, unless you know this operation is going to be performed many, many times on lists orders of magnitudes bigger, any difference in speed or memory utilization will likely be unmeasurable in the overall program. Get the program to work correctly and then optimize if and where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking speed efficience and manipulate series of integers, You should use the standard array module instead:

```
>>> import array
>>> my_array = array.array('i', [1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> my_array = my_array[3:]
>>> my_array.insert(0,123)
>>> my_array
array('i', [123, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

The key thing is to avoid moving large numbers of list items more than absolutely have to. Slice assignment, as far as i'm aware, still involves moving the items around the slice, which is bad news.

How do you recognise when you have a sequence of items which need to be replaced? I'll assume you have a function like:

```
def replacement(objects, startIndex):
    "returns a pair (numberOfObjectsToReplace, replacementObject), or None if the should be no replacement"
```

I'd then do:

```
def replaceAll(objects):
    src = 0
    dst = 0
    while (src < len(objects)):
        replacementInfo = replacement(objects, src)
        if (replacementInfo != None):
            numberOfObjectsToReplace, replacementObject = replacementInfo
        else:
            numberOfObjectsToReplace = 1
            replacementObject = objects[src]
        objects[dst] = replacementObject
        src = src + numberOfObjectsToReplace
        dst = dst + 1
    del objects[dst:]
```

This code still does a few more loads and stores than it absolutely has to, but not many.